# Unification engine sharing with instagram giving execution error

Tags: instagram, unification, unificationengine

When I am using code as per unification engine then its working fine but I am getting this error in our end

```
Requests_Exception in cURL.php line 422: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

But when I am checking on instagram then image and message shared on instagram so why unification engine giving me this problem in instagram sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this as per time

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); // the timeout in seconds
```

OR

```
set_time_limit($seconds)
```

Comment: Your are also proving me solutions of Instagram let me check thanks

Comment: Thanks kuleeep its working as per my application its related with timing

Comment: Yes, its true Thanks